# How does a shell script execute another shell script from within itself

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

My question is how does a shell script execute another shell script does it spawn in a new process? or is it executed in the same process as the script that called it? A example would be a Python script that is executed from a shell script after a condition is met also how would someone write this shell script where it would spawn the Python script and then exit itself without killing the Python script

Comment: The shell and the Python interpreter are different [programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program), so they _have to_ be run as different [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). However, I am sorry this question is too broad. (1. executing a shell script from another shell script, 2. executing Python script from a shell script, 3. keeping a Python script running after the parent shell script finishes) Please focus on one topic in one question to get meaningful answers, be as specific as possible and consider posting the code you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes shell also will spawn new process if you invoke shell script within shell.
if you want to spawn python script and exit without killing, run python in background in shell script/ or disown python process.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html

Comment: Thank you for answering one more question would i run Python in the background with &? Or something else

Answer (score 0):

Python can spawn new processes and control their lives.

You can create and manage them using modules such as [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html): "*The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.*"

If you want to run them on other threads, you can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html): "*multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the threading module.*"

Shell scripts are something different, maybe [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/how-to-correctly-start-an-application-from-a-shell/305769) (and its answers) can help you understand shell scripts launching other scripts :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will read the provided link about shell scripts